# Twitter API Search App, return certain json results

Tags: python, json, api, twitter

```
import json
dict1 = {}
dict2 = {}
def js_r(tweets):
   with open(tweets) as js_r:
       # return(json.load(f_in))

       return(json.loads(json.dumps([])))
       [{}, {}]
       return json.loads(json.loads(get_info))
       return(json.load(f_in))
       result = json.loads(output)
       print(result)
       print(result['contributors'])
if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_data = js_r('tweets.json')
    print(my_data)
```

How do I access and print only user from the json file?

Comment: could u give an example of the JSON that u get?

Answer (score 0):

**just use**

```
with open('tweets.json') as f:
    result = json.load(f)
    print(result)
    print(result['contributors'])
```

---

In your code you are using `with open(tweets) as js_r:` where `js_r` is also a name of your method. use different variable name for that. if you don't want to make method you can directly use my answer.

And

`json.loads()` is for string input, use `json.load()`

**you can try this**

```
result = []
for line in open('tweets.json', 'r'):
    result.append(json.loads(line))
print(result)
```

Comment: raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 8378)

Comment: so edited it again like this with open('tweets.json') as f:


        return(json.loads(json.dumps([])))
        [{}, {}]
        result = json.load(f)
        print(result)
        print(result['contributors'])

Comment: howeverresults do not print

Comment: JSONDecodeError occurs when your json format is wrong, please provide your json file data. or verify that

Comment: does this helped you?